# How do I make openssl_encrypt pad the input to the required block size?

Tags: php, encryption, padding, php-openssl, php-7.1

My code works if I manually pad my string to the length of 32.
My question is: Is there a way to make the openSSL pad the data, or do I always have to do it for it?

Working:

```
 openssl_encrypt ("my baba is over the ocean1111111", 'AES-256-CBC', $MY_SECRET_KEY,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$MY_IV);
```

Not working:

```
openssl_encrypt ("my baba is over the ocean", 'AES-256-CBC', $MY_SECRET_KEY,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$MY_IV);
```

I solve this currently by self padding:

```
$pad = 32 - (strlen("my baba is over the ocean") % 32);
$clear = "my baba is over the ocean" . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); //encrypt this string
```

Comment: The required block size for AES is 16. I'm guessing your choice of 0's padding is confusing the machinery.

Comment: Can you not intentionally use PKCS5 as your padding scheme in place of where you currently have zero padding?

Comment: @LukePark is there a built in way to do it? btw -> notice I pad the block myself and not with zeros

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Luke Park said, instead of explicitly telling `openssl_encrypt` to use `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, simply remove that option from the parameter and it will default to the [PKCS #7 padding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) (fills the rest of the block with `0x0n` where *n* is the number of bytes necessary; + 16 `0x00` if the block is already complete). *Note: PKCS #5 as referenced by Luke and PKCS #7 are effectively identical in this scenario.*

From [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php):

> Without using OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, you will automatically get PKCS#7 padding.

So you should be calling:

```
openssl_encrypt("my baba is over the ocean", 'AES-256-CBC', $MY_SECRET_KEY, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $MY_IV);
```

Comment: What confused me was the Name, I assumed it means padding with ZEROs. while in truth it was meant as NO PADDING.

Comment: I want to generate a part of a URL string using this method. But the URL being generated is consisting of such random bytes that the system is not being able understand it. Gibberish text appears when printing it out. 
Is there any other solution in such case?

Comment: You should encode the cipher text with a URL-safe encoding like [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) or [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (with URL modifications in place).