# php7.1 openssl encrypt with aes_128 ecb PKCS 7padding get wrong result

Tags: php, openssl, aes, padding

I use openssl to encrypt hex data .output is different right output(longer than right output). [online encrypt web site](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/)  , I think maybe need to set padding .but I find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211778/how-do-i-make-openssl-encrypt-pad-the-input-to-the-required-block-size),the answer said pkcs7padding is default setting.So what I miss ?

```
//secret hex '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c'
//input  hex '6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172aae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51'
//right output hex '3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97f5d3d58503b9699de785895a96fdbaaf'


$secret = '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c';
$input = '6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172aae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51';
$output = openssl_encrypt(hex2bin($input),'aes-128-ecb',hex2bin($key),OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

echo bin2hex($output); 
//3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97f5d3d58503b9699de785895a96fdbaafa254be88e037ddd9d79fb6411c3f9df8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
openssl_encrypt(hex2bin($input),'aes-128-ecb',hex2bin($key),OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```