# How to decrypt a SalesForce generated string in php

Tags: php, encryption, salesforce

The Salesforce developer has encrypted a string, eg. 0050000162 in SalesForce
using encryptWithManagedIV and a key that he has shared with me and the encryption standard AES-256 CBC
and passed it along in a url eg. https://a.domain.com/vEmJWoxXyhfTDSrRstf1NYpIB+s5LObcstvFVTUAcb8=

I have tried to decrypted as such

```
openssl_decrypt("vEmJWoxXyhfTDSrRstf1NYpIB+s5LObcstvFVTUAcb8=", "aes-256-cbc", SHARED_CRYPT_KEY);
```

also

```
openssl_decrypt(urldecode("vEmJWoxXyhfTDSrRstf1NYpIB+s5LObcstvFVTUAcb8="), "aes-256-cbc", SHARED_CRYPT_KEY);
```

and

```
openssl_decrypt(base64url_decode("vEmJWoxXyhfTDSrRstf1NYpIB+s5LObcstvFVTUAcb8="), "aes-256-cbc", SHARED_CRYPT_KEY);
function base64url_decode($base64url)
{
    $base64 = strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/');
    $plainText = base64_decode($base64);
    return ($plainText);
}
```

The other developer has been able to decrypt in SalesForce with below code

```
Blob bEncryptKey = Blob.valueOf(encryptKey);
Blob bDataToEncrypt = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(quoteNumberEncrypted);
Blob decrypted = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', bEncryptKey, bDataToEncrypt);
sQuoteNumberEncrypted =  decrypted.toString();
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Frank

Comment: You need to remove IV from the binary blob and pass the remaining blob and extracted IV to openssl_decrypt - translate [this example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271648/encrypting-and-or-decrypting-ciphertext-with-the-provided-initialization-vector/) to PHP. You will also need to deal with padding. Salesforce uses PKCS7 padding and so does [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165071/php-mcrypt-to-openssl-bf-cbc-how-to-get-the-same-encrypted-value/) by default, you'll need to make sure the data blob will remain correctly padded after you break out the IV.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am being sent an encrypted string via url that was encrypted in SalesForce with encryptWithManagedIV. Not sure if you re telling to tell the SalesForce developer to do something or your instructions are for me in PHP.

Comment: Instructions are for you in PHP

Comment: Can you clarify this "you'll need to make sure the data blob will remain correctly padded after you break out the IV"

Here is what I got so far
```
$uuid = "vEmJWoxXyhfTDSrRstf1NYpIB+s5LObcstvFVTUAcb8=""; 
$encodedCipherTextAndIV = bin2hex($uuid);
$encodedCiphertext = substr($encodedCipherTextAndIV, 32);
$encodedIV = substr($encodedCipherTextAndIV, 0, 32);
$ciphertext = hex2bin($encodedCiphertext);
$IV = hex2bin($encodedIV);
var_dump( openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, QUOTE_CRYPT_CIPHER, QUOTE_CRYPT_KEY,0,$IV) );
```
outputs false

Comment: You'll have to play with padding based on the referenced answer above and make sure the padding from Salesforce matches the padding in your deconstructed blobs

Comment: ...and the padding in deconstructed blobs matches padding expected by openssl_decrypt